# Keyword Search in Query editor

Tags: powerbi

I have create a calculated column using the below DAX formula based on the google reference. The below code helps me to identify the keywords in the description and if there are more than one match that will given separated by space/comma. The keywords are available in separate table with single column. Due to other requirements (i.e., unpivoting) I need to convert this keyword search analysis in M code so that I can do all these in the Query editor itself. Is there a way to perform the same?

```
Matchedkey_Description = 
    var result = 
        CONCATENATEX(
             'Keywords',
            IF(
                SEARCH(FIRSTNONBLANK('Keywords'[keys],1),'Data'[Description],,999)<>999,
                'Keywords'[keys],
                ""
            )," "
        )
RETURN
IF(
    result <> BLANK(),
    result,
    " "
)
```

Sample data: Keywords as a separate table like below

[image]

And the Data looks like below to which the keyword match columns needs to added

[image]

Comment: add sample data and your expected output.

Comment: @mkRabbani - added the sample data